# Using Boot Camp on an already partitioned harddrive

Tags: macos, partitioning, macbook, boot-camp

I want to install Windows 7 via Boot Camp on a Mac.

I already split the harddrive into a few partition.

Everytime I try to use Boot Camp it says (freely translated):

> The start volume can't be partitioned or recovered as a single partition.
>     In order to install Windows the start volume has to be either a Mac OS-Extended (Journaled) formated single volume or be partitioned by Boot Camp

I don't want to partition it again with Boot Camp (unless everything can stay like it is now (dual-boot OSX 10.6.7, 10.7 and a data-partition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Windows on Bootcamp with multiple partitions is not straightforward and requires a bit of command line work, as well as installing a new boot menu. You will have to tailor [these instructions](http://wiki.onmac.net/index.php/Triple_Boot_via_BootCamp) a bit to have them apply, but the general idea is correct. In my experience, you cannot use the GUI form of Bootcamp to install Windows when the computer has multiple partitions.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Since this way is more complicated I'm turning all partitions into disk images, saving them, merging the partitions and use Boot Camp then.

Comment: Sounds like that would work too.